# Jqgrid edit popup show &nbsp; in Fields having null values

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid for listing and basic crud operations. On one of the pages there are many nullable fields present on the form. When some values are left blank when adding the entity, it saves those fields in db with null (which is fine). But when same field is edited in jqgrid edit popup, textboxes for these fields contain  . How can I solve this problem

below figure is the update dialog that appears when I click a row in grid and select edit

[image]

**UPdate 2**
I don't have jqgrid.editform.js but the code Oleg mentioned was directly present in jquery.JQGrid.min.js. I removed the lines and now that code looks like

```
switch(C[G].edittype)
{
    case "password":
    case "text":
    case "button":
    case "image":
    case "textarea":
        if(A=="&nbsp;"||A=="&#160;"||(A.length==1 && A.charCodeAt(0)==160)) {
            A = "";
            alert("here");
        }
        alert(A);
        a("#"+r,"#"+v).val(A);
        break;
    case "select":
```

I have put two alert messages to check if the code path is executed but I found no alert when running the page. What could be wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should just use the corresponding [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions) option to solve the problem:

```js
editoptions: {NullIfEmpty: true}
```

**UPDATED**: If I understand correctly your problem now you can use `beforeSubmit` or `onclickSubmit` callback of form editing to *modify* or to delete all empty values from the `postdata` parameter. You can for example use `for-in` loop to enumerate all properties of `posdata`. If the value of some parameter is empty you can use `delete` to remove the property or use `= null` to change empty string to `null`. In both cases you should have `null` as the values of empty editing values.

**UPDATED 2**: The version 3.6.5 which you use is really **very old**. Fortunately I have the version of jqGrid in my archive. I hope that the reason of your problem is bug in the old version of the code. If you use non-minimized version of jqGrid you can open `grid.formedit.js` file and remove lines 832-833:

```
$("#"+nm,"#"+fmid).val(tmp);
break;
```

between `case "image":` and `case "textarea":`. The code should look like in the current version of jqGrid: see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.formedit.js#L575-L582). To fix the problem in minimized version of jqGrid you should search for the text `case "button":case "image":` and remove `a("#"+r,"#"+v).val(A);break;` which is directly after `case "button":case "image":` and before `case "textarea":`.

Comment: In the linki you mentioned, they have following description for NullIfEmpty `If set to true a string 'null' is send to the server when the data in that field is empty`. My problem is not sending null for empty fields,  the problem is to show empty fields when data is null in db for relevent columns.

Comment: It goes without saying that I have checked it on one column and it does not solve the mentioned problem

Comment: The problem seems peculiar to text boxes. if I change a textbox to text area the problem vanishes. Any ideas?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: I updated my answer. I hope that I understand it correctly now.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for all the pain. I updated the answer to further elaborate the problem. you can see &nbsp in many textboxes. I have confirmed that in db these field values are null (which is fine). I only want to get rid of this &nbsp when form is rendered

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: The problem is that I have to guess what you do. You wrote for example about usage `null` in the data. Typically the data returned from the server contains only empty strings instead of `null`. Do you use `jsonReader` with `repeatitems: false`? After you posted the screenshort I think that I start to understand what problem you have. It would be good if you post more full demo which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: You can try to set `editoptions: {defaultValue: ""}`. The version 3.6.5 is really **very old**. I found the copy of the code. If I understand correctly your problem, the problem which you describe isn't exist in current version of jqGrid. Compare the part of the code of `grid.formedit.js` after `case "image":` with the current version. To fix the problem you should remove the lines `$("#"+nm,"#"+fmid).val(tmp);` after `case "image":`. In Min-ver search for `case "button":case "image":` and remove `a("#"+r,"#"+v).val(A);break;` between `case "image":` and `case "textarea":`

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: See **UPDATED 2** part of my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for continuous attention to this problem. plz have a look at update 2 on the question.

Comment: strange things happening. clicking edit for a row first time does not trigger the changed code but if I cancel the edit popup and then again click edit for the same row, the alerts are triggered and I get the textboxes just fine i.e without &nbsp;

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: Sorry, did you have caching problem with old non-modified `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`? Is the problem solved now?

Comment: No, its not caching problem. its something like: load the page select a row in grid, press edit and I get the same &nbsp in text fields. Then I cancel the popup and press edit again (no page refresh) this time text fields do not contain undesired &nbsp;. No I wonder why that switch statement is not called first time I press edit