# remove &nbsp from jqgrid cells

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have create jqGrid table with empty cells, but when I click on cells by default it displays &nbsp. Where I need to change the code to trim &nbsp

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var lastsel;
    var clientArray = [];

    $("#bms-record-grooms").jqGrid({
        // data: mydata,
        datatype: "local",
        height: '100%',
        Width: '100%',
        scroll: true,
        rowNum: 5,
        scrollOffset: 0,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        colNames: ['SNo', 'Name', 'Duration', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Predecessors', 'Resources'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
                   { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100, editable: true, edit: "Refresh" },
                   { name: 'duration', index: 'duration', width: 100, editable: true },
                   { name: 'startdate', index: 'Date', width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "date" },
                   { name: 'enddate', index: 'Date', width: 100, editable: true, sorttype: "date" },
                   { name: 'predecessors', index: 'predecessors', width: 100, editable: true },
                   { name: 'Resources', index: 'resources', width: 100, editable: true}],
        pager: "#plist47",
        viewrecords: true,
        sortname: 'name',
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#bms-record-grooms').saveRow(lastsel);
                jQuery('#bms-record-grooms').jqGrid('editRow', id, true, pickdates, null, 'clientArray', null, function(res) {
                    var idAsNumber = parseInt(id, 10);
                    var nextId = idAsNumber + 1;
                    jQuery('#bms-record-grooms').setSelection(nextId, true);
                    jQuery('#' + nextId + '_Name').focus();
                });
                lastsel = id;
            }
        },
        loadComplete: function() { },
        caption: "Grouping Array Data",
        editurl: "clientArray"
    });
    for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
       jQuery("#bms-record-grooms").addRowData(i, {
          id: i, name: "", duration: "", startdate: "", enddate: "", predecessors: "", Resources: ""
         }, "");
    }
});

function pickdates(id) {
    jQuery("#" + id + "_startdate", "#bms-record-grooms").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
    });
    jQuery("#" + id + "_enddate", "#bms-record-grooms").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd"
    });
}
```

In `jqgrid` cell it displayed `&nbsp` instead of empty cells. How can I remove this?

Comment: What version of jqGrid are you using?

Comment: Does this one help? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848311/jqgrid-edit-popup-show-nbsp-in-fields-having-null-values